# My rst README is not formatted on pypi.python.org

Tags: python, python-2.7, pypi

When I submit my package to the Python Package Index (https://pypi.python.org/pypi) my README file, which is written with valid reStructuredText and saved as README.rst, is displayed as plain text without any formatting.

I have run it through validators (rstctl and collective.checkdocs) and no errors are returned.

My package is at:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lcinvestor

It's in github at:
https://github.com/jgillick/LendingClubAutoInvestor

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It turns out that the answer from @sigmavirus regarding the links was close. I started a [discussion](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2013-May/020744.html) on the distutils mailing list and found out that in-page links (i.e. #minimum-cash) are not allowed by the pypi reStructuredText parser and will invalidate the entire document.

It seems that pypi uses a whitelist to filter link protocols (http vs ftp vs gopher), and sees '#' as an invalid protocol. It seems like this would be pretty easy to fix on their end, but until then, I'll be removing my in-page anchor links.

Comment: PyPI's reStructuredText renderer also chokes on relative links, even if they aren't anchors. I had to switch out my relative links with full paths (starting with `https://`), but it works now. https://github.com/chbrown/filesequence/commit/728ac3db4bf2ae2c640d48e065fb3aed0e937acc

Comment: You may use the my filtering code above for eliminating all invalid constructs for PyPi that I know of.

Answer (score 22):

- You may use [`collective.checkdocs`](https://github.com/collective/collective.checkdocs) package to detect invalid constructs:

  `pip install collective.checkdocs
   python setup.py checkdocs`
- You may then use the following python function to filter-out *sphinx-only* constructs (it might be necessary to add more regexes, to match your content):

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""
Cleans-up Sphinx-only constructs (ie from README.rst),
so that *PyPi* can format it properly.

To check for remaining errors, install ``sphinx`` and run::

        python setup.py --long-description | sed -file 'this_file.sed' | rst2html.py  --halt=warning

"""

import re
import sys, io


def yield_sphinx_only_markup(lines):
    """
    :param file_inp:     a `filename` or ``sys.stdin``?
    :param file_out:     a `filename` or ``sys.stdout`?`

    """
    substs = [
        ## Selected Sphinx-only Roles.
        #
        (r':abbr:`([^`]+)`',        r'\1'),
        (r':ref:`([^`]+)`',         r'`\1`_'),
        (r':term:`([^`]+)`',        r'**\1**'),
        (r':dfn:`([^`]+)`',         r'**\1**'),
        (r':(samp|guilabel|menuselection):`([^`]+)`',        r'``\2``'),


        ## Sphinx-only roles:
        #        :foo:`bar`   --> foo(``bar``)
        #        :a:foo:`bar` XXX afoo(``bar``)
        #
        #(r'(:(\w+))?:(\w+):`([^`]*)`', r'\2\3(``\4``)'),
        (r':(\w+):`([^`]*)`', r'\1(``\2``)'),


        ## Sphinx-only Directives.
        #
        (r'\.\. doctest',           r'code-block'),
        (r'\.\. plot::',            r'.. '),
        (r'\.\. seealso',           r'info'),
        (r'\.\. glossary',          r'rubric'),
        (r'\.\. figure::',          r'.. '),


        ## Other
        #
        (r'\|version\|',              r'x.x.x'),
    ]

    regex_subs = [ (re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE), sub) for (regex, sub) in substs ]

    def clean_line(line):
        try:
            for (regex, sub) in regex_subs:
                line = regex.sub(sub, line)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("ERROR: %s, (line(%s)"%(regex, sub))
            raise ex

        return line

    for line in lines:
        yield clean_line(line)
```

and/or in your `setup.py` file, use something like this::

```python
def read_text_lines(fname):
    with io.open(os.path.join(mydir, fname)) as fd:
        return fd.readlines()

readme_lines = read_text_lines('README.rst')
long_desc = ''.join(yield_sphinx_only_markup(readme_lines)),
```

Alternatively you can use the `sed` unix-utility with this file:

```
## Sed-file to clean-up README.rst from Sphinx-only constructs,
##   so that *PyPi* can format it properly.
##   To check for remaining errors, install ``sphinx`` and run:
##
##          sed -f "this_file.txt" README.rst | rst2html.py  --halt=warning
##

## Selected Sphinx-only Roles.
#
s/:abbr:`\([^`]*\)`/\1/gi
s/:ref:`\([^`]*\)`/`\1`_/gi
s/:term:`\([^`]*\)`/**\1**/gi
s/:dfn:`\([^`]*\)`/**\1**/gi
s/:\(samp\|guilabel\|menuselection\):`\([^`]*\)`/``\1``/gi


## Sphinx-only roles:
#        :foo:`bar` --> foo(``bar``)
#
s/:\([a-z]*\):`\([^`]*\)`/\1(``\2``)/gi


## Sphinx-only Directives.
#
s/\.\. +doctest/code-block/i
s/\.\. +plot/raw/i
s/\.\. +seealso/info/i
s/\.\. +glossary/rubric/i
s/\.\. +figure::/../i


## Other
#
s/|version|/x.x.x/gi
```

Comment: good tip for `checkdocs` that found the error that was breaking my readme when `python setup.py check --restructuredtext` found nothing wrong

Comment: It’s pretty hard to use without setup.py though: `from setuptools import Distribution; from collective.checkdocs import checkdocs; checkdocs(Distribution(dict(long_description=open("README.rst").read()))).run()`

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT:** You can use the following to find errors in your RST that will show up on PyPI:

```
twine check
```

You'll need `twine` version 1.12.0 or higher. If you don't have it you can install or update it using:

```
pip install --upgrade twine
```

[Source](https://packaging.python.org/guides/making-a-pypi-friendly-readme/#validating-restructuredtext-markup)

---

**Deprecated answer:**

```
python setup.py check --restructuredtext
```

[Source](http://inre.dundeemt.com/2014-05-04/pypi-vs-readme-rst-a-tale-of-frustration-and-unnecessary-binding/)

Comment: For me this only worked after `pip install readme`. However, then it showed the problem no other checker caught.

Comment: This seems to be deprecated meanwhile: ``warning: Check: This command has been deprecated. Use `twine check` instead: https://packaging.python.org/guides/making-a-pypi-friendly-readme#validating-restructuredtext-markup
`` and referring us to https://packaging.python.org/guides/making-a-pypi-friendly-readme/#validating-restructuredtext-markup

Comment: `twine check` needs one or more arguments in the form of distribution files built. That is of course not very useful to check **up front** if the resulting disribution files would display correctly. (building those distriution files for one of my C extensions takes over an hour, wasted if you run `twine check dist/*` and find you can start over)

Answer (score 8):

The first thing that pops out at me (after a quick scan) is that in your Advanced Filters section you use two underscores after a link, e.g.,

```
`Link text <http://example.com>`__
```

Where it should be

```
`Link text <http://example.com>`_
```

It's odd that the reStructuredText checkers didn't catch that. If you have docutils installed as well, you can run `rst2html.py README.rst` and it should print out the HTML. If there are errors it will fail and tell you where the errors were.

Also, fair warning, lists should have no leading spaces, i.e., you have

```
 - foo
 - bar
```

Instead of

```
- foo
- bar
```

(To make it more visually clear)

```
- foo # correct
 - one too many for a regular list, it will show up as a quoted list
```

---

Also, relative linking doesn't work like so `Text to link <#link>_`. If you want to link to a separate section you have to do the following:

```
Here's my `link <section_name>`_ to the other section.

.. Other stuff here ...

.. _section_name:

Min/Max Investment Opportunities and Other Foo Biz Baz
------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5):

**I had the same problem** when uploading my python module to pypi .

Later I checked the **README.rst** for errors using **`rst-lint`** which showed that my readme file was right.

I found that the problem was not in the README file but in **setup.py** itself.

### Follow the below points while writing Readme and setup.py

- DO NOT WRITE MULTI LINE python strings for description or summary or anything that goes into the setup( ) arguments .
- Don't use relative links in the README file .(like ./path1/path2 ).
- Make sure the rst syntax is all right using a checking tool like rst-lint.
- If you have a markdown file , you can convert it to Restructured text using **pandoc** easily

Comment: In my case it was indeed a mulit line string for description (not even long_description!). Crazy... your answer saved my hours, thank you!