# reStructuredText: README.rst not parsing on PyPI

Tags: python, restructuredtext, pypi

I have a Python project that is hosted on both Github and PyPI.

On Github: https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/master/README.rst

On PyPi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/textblob

**My README.rst doesn't seem to be formatting correctly on PyPI, but it looks fine on Github.**

I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367770/my-rst-readme-is-not-formatted-on-pypi-python-org), but I don't have any in-page links, so that's not the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My rst README is not formatted on pypi.python.org](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367770/my-rst-readme-is-not-formatted-on-pypi-python-org)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Historical note**: *this answer covered a release of PyPI that is no longer used, as it has since been replaced by a new server called [Warehouse](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse), which has been tracking docutils releases as they come out (which at the time of this note, was 0.16). If you are having issues with Restructured Text rendering *today*, this answer will no longer help you.*

*Original answer follows.*

---

You are using a newer text role, [`:code:`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#code).

PyPI appears to only support docutils 0.8, with `code` and `code-block` added to the PyPI parser directly, which means that `:code:` is *not* supported.

GitHub uses a newer version of docutils (0.9 or 0.10).

Remove the `:code:` role altogether, so replace:

```
:code:`sentiment`
```

with:

```
`sentiment`
```

etc.

Answer (score 6):

For a [package I uploaded recently](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/TaarifaAPI), the issue was a relative link (not an in-page link) in the `README.rst` to our contribution guidelines, which [renders fine on GitHub](https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files), but trips up rendering on PyPI.

To fix this, I temporarily turned the link into an absolute link, called

```
python setup.py register
```

to update the metadata and backed out the change without committing it.

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same problem** when uploading my python module to pypi .

Later I checked the **README.rst** for errors using **`rst-lint`** which showed that my readme file was right. You can also use `restructuredtext_link` package for python to check the rst file for any errors or warnings .

I found that the problem was not in the README file but in **setup.py** itself.

### Follow the below points while writing Readme and setup.py

- DO NOT WRITE MULTI LINE python strings for description or summary or anything that goes into the setup( ) arguments .
- Don't use relative links in the README file .(like ./path1/path2 ).
- Make sure the rst syntax is all right using a checking tool like rst-lint.
- If you have a markdown file , you can convert it to Restructured text using **pandoc** easily.

Make sure that you keep these in mind while writing README .