# PyPI README.rst format issue

Tags: python, restructuredtext, pypi, readme

I have a Python package. I added a `README.rst` file to display the description. It is displaying properly in [GitHub](https://github.com/dcsolvere/vmonere/blob/master/README.rst)

However, on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vmonere) my RST file is not formatted; it is displaying the raw content.

You can find the `setup.py` file [here](https://github.com/dcsolvere/vmonere/blob/master/setup.py). Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: The answer usually is: test locally with an older version of docutils as GitHub uses a newer version than PyPI does.

Comment: Related: [reStructuredText: README.rst not parsing on PyPI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17401132) (although you are not using `:code:`). Perhaps the `:alt:`'s are not supported?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - It helps. `:alt:`  works but some header issue.Thank you