# reStructuredText: README.rst not working on PyPI

Tags: python, restructuredtext, pypi

I have created a package on github [django-joyride](https://github.com/intellisense/django-joyride), after [publishing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-joyride/0.1.2) it to pypi it is not showing the `README.rst` properly. I have checked my syntax [here](http://rst.ninjs.org/?n=04871bb52f89e5c4b5ec4937e820d7aa&theme=nature) on an online viewer and you can see it works fine. What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you verified that none of the potential problems discussed at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367770/my-rst-readme-is-not-formatted-on-pypi-python-org) are affecting you?

Comment: The only thing from that question I can confirm is that I have double underscore after URL as suggested in second answer ``Link text <http://example.com>__``

Comment: Your source file seems to have very strange line endings (`\r\r\n`?). That might throw the parser off...

Comment: Use helper tool like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.checkdocs/ to detect RST errors before PyPi upload

Answer (score 2):

**I had the same problem** when uploading my python module to pypi .

Later I checked the **README.rst** for errors using **`rst-lint`** which showed that my readme file was right. You can also use `restructuredtext_link` package for python to check the rst file for any errors or warnings .

I found that the problem was not in the README file but in **setup.py** itself.

### Follow the below points while writing Readme and setup.py

- DO NOT WRITE MULTI LINE python strings for description or summary or anything that goes into the setup( ) arguments .
- Don't use relative links in the README file .(like ./path1/path2 ).
- Make sure the rst syntax is all right using a checking tool like rst-lint.
- If you have a markdown file , you can convert it to Restructured text using **pandoc** easily.

Also do not use any new docutils syntax since Pypi doesn't use the latest version as Github does.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that pypi gets confused because you have both a `README.md` and a `README.rst` file. Try to delete the `.md` one; github can handle `README.rst` fine.

Comment: Have the same problem. Not sure this is the reason, because it's possible to edit the information. I changed the information from rst to markdown and vice-versa, neither of them works for me.